# $rootScope in angularjs custom property gone after injection

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

[**Problem Related codepen**](http://codepen.io/eldyvoon/pen/ONBZEJ)

I declared `$rootScope.myproperty` in main controller and it can be accessed in other controllers.

But in one of the controller I have to inject `$rootScope` as I used `$watch`. Then when I check back `$rootScope.myproperty` it became undefined. Strange why would this happens?

Comment: Added an answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because you were using `$rootScope` as a variable and assigning an object to it

```
$rootScope = { myproperty: 'root abc' };
```

This is wrong. Instead you should add attributes to it as below and it will work:

```
$rootScope.myproperty = 'root abc';
```

I have updated the codepen and its working : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaeyJm

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwaJBo)

The problem is you have injected `$rootScope` into `AttendeesCtrl` controller. You don't need to inject `$rootScope` into a controller. When you inject `$scope`, you automatically get access to anything defined in `$rootScope` due to the [prototypal inheritance of JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). So `AttendeesCtrl` controller should look like this:

```
.controller('AttendeesCtrl', function($scope) {

  //I used $watch and $rootScope somehere so I have to inject $rootScope in this controller
  $scope.myproperty = $rootScope.myproperty;
});
```

For detail, you can have a look at the AngularJS [Scope Hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies).

Hope that solve your problem.